# Redirect specific URL in AWS CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, redirect, amazon-cloudfront

Can Amazon **CloudFront** redirect specific URL. For example when someone requested the page *somename/logging.html*, to open *page_name.html*.

Can this be done by placing the *page_name.html* in **S3** bucket. Creating a **origin** with that bucket, and last to create **behavior** with **path pattern** */logging.html* and **origin** the created origin with the bucket.